# JavaFX button grows 1 pixel bottom on hover, how can I disable it growing?

Tags: javafx

I'm a bit new to JavaFX, I've found a problem with styling buttons, whenever I hover a button it grows 1 pixel bottom, I guess it's a standard feature of buttons but I want to disable it, though I have no idea on how to actually do it.

Here's a picture where you can see it:

[image]

Clearly the red close button is bigger than the minimize button by 1 pixel bottom (you can't see it there but my mouse is hovering the red button).

Any ideas on how to remove that behaviour? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's the same problem with the minus button this time:

[image]

Edit: Buttons CSS:

```
.windowbar-button {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
.windowbar-button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #474748;
    -fx-cursor: hand;
}

.button-close:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #E81123;
}
```

windowbar-button applies to both buttons, button-close applies only to the close button.

Comment: You could check , `-fx-border-color: blue ;` and see if there is a change in border when you hover. Sometimes the border is used to give in a bit of depth.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the HBox height from 33 to 32, then made both buttons 32 height and added a -2 margin top, it got fixed. It's as if the buttons never really centered vertically on the HBox but instead always had a 2 pixel margin top (though they didn't).

Comment: This could be a decent question/answer if you made a compilable example, and show the the css you used to solve your problem. As it stands, it's a bit uclear what was wrong and what you did.

Comment: @matt I plan on updating it, I don't have time though now as I need to finish what I was working on ASAP, I'll definitely try to add a working example tomorrow.